# Redefine a method for unit tests

Tags: ruby, unit-testing

I'm not so string in ruby syntax, but if I understand something when learning it, you can do everything, no restrictions, lets say I got a class method, and I want to redefine it in a unit test to isolate the stuff I'm testing, how do i do that? lets say class name is foo and instance method is bar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby: Alter class static method in a code block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014048/ruby-alter-class-static-method-in-a-code-block)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Test::Redef](https://github.com/nearbuy/test-redef) is a gem designed to do exactly this.

```
test "some method on Foo should be called because under normal circumstances it something useful like send network traffic" do
  Test::Redef.rd(
    'Foo#bar'  => proc {|args| puts 'new behavior goes here!'},
    'Foo#baz'  => :empty,   # same as => proc { }
    'Foo#quux' => :wiretap, # no behavior change but you get invocation tracking
    'Foo.blat' => :empty,   # class method
  ) do |rd|

    # code under test


    assert_equal [['invocation 1 arg 1', 'invocation 1 arg 2'], 
                  ['invocation 2 arg 1'],
                 ], rd[:bar].args, 'Foo#bar was called with the right arguments'
  end

  # now all methods are back to normal
end
```